# Opening developer tools affecting divs in DOM

Tags: dom, developer-tools

I feel like a crazy person asking this, but I have a form on my page which "follows" you down the page as you scroll. The code works beautifully, except for one crazy bug; when I open chrome's developer tools and my form has the .fixed class added, the form gets thrown off the page. I have no idea why this is happening, or how to fix it, as I didn't think opening the developer tools would affect the DOM at all. Any idea why this is happening, or how to fix it? Here's the JS/css snippet:

```
if (!msie6) {
  var top = $('.form-frame').offset().top - parseFloat($('.form-frame').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= top) {
      // if so, add the fixed class
      $('.form-frame').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $('.form-frame').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
}
```

The sass is as follows:

```
.form-container
  position: absolute
  right: 20px
  top: 20px

.form-frame
   text-align: center
   width: 250px

.form-frame.fixed 
  position: fixed
  top: 20px
```

Answer (score 1):

Opening the Chrome dev tools, in my experience, can affect things "fixed" to a bottom of a screen. Try popping the dev tools into a separate window and see if it still is a problem.